# zlib module issue for local user

Tags: python, python-2.7, zlib

My requirement is to install NodeJS using sources (v8.9.4) for a local user (no root access) on Oracle Linux. When I ran the 'configure' and 'make install' it complained that the Python version was not 2.7.

Since there was no root access and I could not upgrade Python, I installed Python for the local user with the steps below.

I downloaded the sources (Python-2.7.11) and ran the configure (with --prefix option) and 'make install'. 
Updated the PATH and PYTHONPATH variables to use this version of Python for this user.

Now, when I try to configure NodeJS again, it does not complain about Python 2.7 any more but now says:

```
File "tools/compress_json.py", line 6, in <module>
import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

When I checked if zlib was on the system with 'yum list installed zlib', I see

```
zlib.i386   1.2.3-4.el5 installed
zlib.x86_64 1.2.3-4.el5 installed
```

I now do not know

- how the local python version can use this zlib module (or)
- how/if zlib module needs to be configured into python (or)
- if Python has to be installed again with some configuration for getting the zlib module.

I've searched on google and tried a few, but there was nothing conclusive that could help.

Comment: Have you already installed `zlib1g-dev`: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` ?

Comment: I tried based on some posts, dunno if its related to Oracle Linux, but I get 'Command not found' when I try apt-get

Comment: Probably the interpreter cannot fine the modules, try to set the PYTHONPATH variable to include the directories where the modules are installed

Comment: If you are using Oracle Linux, try with this: `sudo yum install zlib-devel`.

Comment: @Gianluca: I had set the PYTHONPATH along with PATH but to no avail.  Sorry for not including that in the question. Have updated it now.

Comment: @Dalton: Tried 'yum install zlib-devel' but it says 'No package zlib-devel available.'.

Comment: Try to install `zlib-devel` as explained here: https://serverfault.com/questions/608781/is-there-a-way-to-install-pip-and-zlib-devel-on-rhel-5-7-without-red-hat-entitle .